# Second generated apk is smaller than the first one(Xamarin.Android, Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, apk, size

`3 months` ago I generated an `apk` file of `Xamarin.Android` project following the steps of the following link:

https://riptutorial.com/xamarin-android/example/29653/preparing-your-apk-in-the-visual-studio

The `apk` size was `65 MB`. I copied the `apk` on my phone, installed the app, the app ran and everything was fine. I continued to work on the project for the next `3 months`, then I tried to generate an `apk` following the steps from the same link, I succeded but the size of the generated `apk` was `10 MB` which is not normal because during these 3 months I've been adding code and files to the project, the second `apk` must have been bigger than the first one (bigger than `65 MB`). When I copied the second `apk` on the phone and installed the app, when I executed it, I got `Unfortunatelly the app has stopped` error message. During the first `apk` creation I created an `Android Key Store` but before the second `apk` creation I deleted it by mistake so I had to create new one. I don't know if that has anything to do with the problem.

Comment: Does the second apk installs and works as it supposed to? Did you have linking enabled first time?

Comment: The second apk installs but when I start it I get `Unfortunatelly the app has stopped` error message. What is `linking enabled first time` and where can I find it to enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Android Options` I put `Linking` to `None` and that solved the problem.